# OpenCL template on Visual Studio and how to write code on it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, opencl, intel

My laptop hardware information :
OS: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3540M CPU @ 3.00 GHz RAM: 16,0 GB Graphics: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000  with Visual Studio 2012.

My question is that if this is correct icon image for OpenCL template or something is missing on installation process. What I am asking is that whether it will work for writing code or any package should reinstalled to fix and see OpenCL icon as "CL" on visual studio.

Thanks for your help!

Here are screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Given the following circumstance, Its hard to tell whether you followed all the steps or not. To be sure, you can try calculating parallel sum or other "hello world" level program to be sure.

Comment: http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/AMD_APP_SDK_Getting_Started_Guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any information how to configure OpenCL on Visual Studio 2012 when using Intel SDK ?  Appreciated many times !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I followed included correct steps to complete installation. The first program I tried has worked  as supposed to work.